# laravel route not working when using two middleware

Tags: php, laravel, routes

in my application there are three routes which can be accessed by **admin** and **superadmin** Middleware but these routes only working in one Middleware i.e. superadmin Middleware.

This is my routes file what i am doing wrong here

```
// Admin Routes  
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin/members', 'AdminController@members');
    Route::get('admin/members/all', 'AdminController@membersAll');
    Route::get('admin/members/unpaid', 'AdminController@membersUnpaid');
    Route::post('admin/members/all', 'AdminController@membersAllAjax');
    Route::get('admin/member/detail/{id}', 'AdminController@memberDetails')
            ->name('memberdetails');

    Route::get('admin/member/remove/{id}', 'AdminController@memberRemove');
    Route::get('admin/member/block/{id}', 'AdminController@memberBlock');
    Route::get('admin/member/unblock/{id}', 'AdminController@memberunBlock');

    Route::post('admin/member/ajax', 'AdminController@memberunAjax');
    Route::get('admin/member/add', 'AdminController@addMember');
    Route::post('admin/member/add', 'AdminController@addMemberDB');

    Route::post('admin/send/message/all', 'AdminController@sendMessageAll');
    Route::post('admin/send/message/single','AdminController@sendMessageSingle');

    Route::post('admin/update/invoice', 'AdminController@updateInvoice');

    Route::post('admin/user/to/member', 'AdminController@addUserMemberDB');

    Route::get('admin/activities', 'AdminController@activities');
    Route::post('admin/activities', 'AdminController@activitiesAdd');

    Route::get('admin/donation', 'AdminController@donation');

    Route::post('admin/edit/user/profile', 'AdminController@editUser');
});

// Admin and SubAdmin Routes
Route::middleware(['superadmin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/members/all', 'AdminController@membersAll');
    Route::post('admin/members/all', 'AdminController@membersAllAjax');
    Route::get('admin/member/detail/{id}', 'AdminController@memberDetails')
            ->name('memberdetails');
    Route::get('subAdmin', 'SuperAdminController@index');
});
```

Comment: Did you get any error on other middleware routes??

Comment: no error but its redirecting on some other route which is not common

Comment: Have you check your middleware for redirections on some situations?

Comment: Your middleware is ```superadmin``` or ```subAdmin``` ?

Comment: yes  there is no other logic added for redirection except this route file

Comment: @Adlan Arif Zakaria superadmin

Comment: Why in your description it is subAdmin? Can you explain more what is you are experiencing and what did you do to create that issue?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake let me edit description

Comment: Where do you get redirected when using superadmin middleware?

Comment: i rediredted when i go via admin not superadmin...and i redirected to admin home

Comment: Is admin home is admin login page? you may have issue with admin authorization.

Answer (score 0):

the second configuration of the route `Route::get('admin/members/all')` wich needs to validate the `superadmin` middleware overwrites the first one wich only need to satisfy `admin`middleware.

if you try to access that route with `superadmin` priviledge, it will work.

now, if you want both `admin` && `superadmin` to access it, put only one configuration in the `admin` middleware group if the `superadmin` satisfies it too.

```
// Admin and SuperAdmin Routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function() {
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin/members', 'AdminController@members');
}

//only SuperAdmin Routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['superadmin']], function() {
    Route::get('admin/members/all', 'AdminController@membersAll');
}
```

otherwise, make another middleware `adminAndSuperAdmin` for those routes.

```
// Admin only Routes  
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function() {
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
}

//superAdmin only Routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['superadmin']], function() {
    Route::get('subAdmin', 'SuperAdminController@index');
});

//Admin and SuperAdmin Routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['adminAndSuperAdmin']], function() {
    Route::get('admin/members', 'AdminController@members');
    Route::get('admin/members/all', 'AdminController@membersAll');
}
```

Comment: but in my case there are only two type user one is admin who can access all routes and another is superadmin which can access only few routes ..i do not want to create third middleware

Comment: @sam999 use the first solution. if a `superadmin` can access routes that have `admin` middleware. How do you check for `admin`or`superadmin` ?

Comment: i am trying first method but getting this error syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'   near this line of code   //only SuperAdmin Routes
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');

Comment: there is admin value in Auth user table

Comment: @sam999 didnt mean for you to copy past it. it was figurative. i'll edit my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your routes using `Route::group`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'member'], function () {
        Route::get('remove/{id}', 'AdminController@memberRemove');
        Route::get('block/{id}', 'AdminController@memberBlock');
        Route::get('unblock/{id}', 'AdminController@memberunBlock');

        Route::post('admin/member/ajax', 'AdminController@memberunAjax');
        Route::get('admin/member/add', 'AdminController@addMember');
        Route::post('admin/member/add', 'AdminController@addMemberDB');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'superadmin'], function () {
            Route::get('detail/{id}', 'AdminController@memberDetails')
                    ->name('memberdetails');
        });
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'members'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@members');

        Route::get('unpaid', 'AdminController@membersUnpaid');
        Route::get('detail/{id}', 'AdminController@memberDetails')
                ->name('memberdetails');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'superadmin'], function () {
            Route::get('all', 'AdminController@membersAll');
            Route::post('all', 'AdminController@membersAllAjax');
        });
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'send/message'], function () {
        Route::post('all', 'AdminController@sendMessageAll');
        Route::post('single','AdminController@sendMessageSingle');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'activities'], function () {  
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@activities');
        Route::post('/', 'AdminController@activitiesAdd');
    });

    Route::post('update/invoice', 'AdminController@updateInvoice');

    Route::post('user/to/member', 'AdminController@addUserMemberDB');

    Route::get('donation', 'AdminController@donation');

    Route::post('edit/user/profile', 'AdminController@editUser');
});
```

Comment: Done. try it now

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Done again. I was forgot some things ;D